# For loop converting dictionary with multiple values to JSON

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary

I have a dictionary containing:

```
d = ('CF', [{'lat': -3.234, 'long': '54.234', 'date': '05-12-1996'}, {'lat': -2.234, 'long': '57.544', 'date': '02-12-1996'}], 'DF': {'lat': -3.234, 'long': '54.234', 'date': '03-12-1996'}])
```

sometimes the keys within the dict contain either one value

```
d = ('k', [v])
```

the keys can also contain two or more values

```
d = ('k', [{v1}, {v2}])
```

I am attempting to convert this dictionary into JSON format and am experiencing many issues. I currently have this which I know is not enough:

```
for i in geodata.items():
    with open('geoJSON.json', 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(i, fp)
```

This doesn't work for all key-values in the dictionary. I was wondering how I would convert this dictionary into JSON, whilst naming the JSON file the key *(CF, DF)* and date which is taken from within the dictionary values *('date': '05-12-1996')*. To achieve a name for the JSON file that is along the lines of 'CF-05-12-1996.json'.

So therefore,

CF-05-12-1996.json would contain:

```
{
'lat': -3.234,
'long': '54.234',
'date': '05-12-1996'
}
```

CF-02-12-1996.json would contain:

```
{
'lat': -2.234,
'long': '57.544',
'date': '02-12-1996'
}
```

and finally, DF-03-12-1996.json would contain:

```
{
'lat': -3.234,
'long': '54.234',
'date': '03-12-1996'
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: create a new dictionary appending every date to the previous "key" and then use `json.dump()`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that geodata.items() returns a list, json.dump() would work if list contains "dict" datatypes. 
You can check using:

```
type(geodata.items()[0])
```

If the list has non-dict datatypes, then you need to check the function.